# Change Pagination/Entries After Select Option To Data tables Using Ajax With Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

load_data_select

```
  <?php   
     //load_data_select.php  
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ajaxtest");  
     function fill_brand($connect)  
     {  
          $output = '';  
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM brand";  
          $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
          {  
               $output .= '<option value="'.$row["brand_id"].'">'.$row["brand_name"].'</option>';  
          }  
          return $output;  
     }  

     function fill_product($connect)  
     {  
          $output = '';  
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";  
          $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
          {  

            echo  '<tr>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row["product_id"].'</td>';
            echo  '<td>'.$row["product_name"].'</td>';  
            echo  '<td>'.$row["brand_id"].'</td>';  
            echo  '</tr>';              
          }  
          return $output;  
     }  
     ?>  
     <!DOCTYPE html>  
     <html>  
          <head>  
               <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Multiple Image Upload</title>  
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
          </head>  
          <body>  
               <br /><br />  
               <div class="container">  

                         <select name="brand" id="brand">  
                              <option value="">Show All Product</option>  
                              <?php echo fill_brand($connect); ?>  
                         </select>  
                         <br /><br />  
                         <!--Testing-->
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tbl">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Brand</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="warehouse">
                              <?php fill_product($connect);?>  

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Brand</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
                </table>
                 <!--Testing-->
               </div>  
          </body>  
     </html>  
     <script>  
     $(document).ready( function () {
        $('.tbl').DataTable();
    } );
     $(document).ready(function(){  
          $('#brand').change(function(){  
               var brand_id = $(this).val();  
               $.ajax({  
                    url:"load_data.php",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:{brand_id:brand_id},  
                    success:function(data){  
                         $('#warehouse').html(data);  
                    }  
               });  
          });  
     });  
     </script>
```

load_data.php

```
<?php  
 //load_data.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ajaxtest");  
 $output = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["brand_id"]))  
 {  
      if($_POST["brand_id"] != '')  
      {  
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE brand_id = '".$_POST["brand_id"]."'";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";  
      }  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {   
            $output .= '<tr>';
            $output .= '<td>'.$row["product_id"].'</td>';
            $output .= '<td>'.$row["product_name"].'</td>';  
            $output .= '<td>'.$row["brand_id"].'</td>';  
            $output .='</tr>';
      }  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Trying to make a select option to search data tables, but after that I realize the data tables pagination and entries cannot change according to the search (Using bootstrap), how should I do and what should I do so that it respond to my select option and respond to show entries on bootstraps data tables

Comment: Please read about **[SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use **[prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)** with **[bound parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**. See **[this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases)** and **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** for some good examples.

Comment: this is testing, i have to see how to do the basic before i can move on to real project.